# Drupal 8 disable template (page & node) cache

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have tried several articles to disable the page and template cache in Drupal 8.  I am not using drush and find it very annoying I have to manually clear the cache after every change.

sites/default/default.services.yaml

1. List item
2. debug: true
3. cache: false
4. auto_reload: true

create sites/settings.php & sites/settings.local.php

1. $config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
2. $config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
3. $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
4. $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
5. $settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';

in development.services.yml add the following

```
    1. twig.config:
        debug: true
        auto_reload: true
        cache: false
```

Rebuild the cache

1. http://yoursite/core/rebuild.php or drush cr

Disable cache in configuration -> performance

Be sure to disable dev tools cache

If I make an adjustment to page.html.twig nothing happens til I clear the cache, any other ideas would be great. This would be the latest version of Drupal 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the steps above I forgot to do one thing

1. Move the settings.local.php inside sites/default
2. Uncomment the following in settings.php

   if (file_exists(**DIR** . '/settings.local.php')) {
     include **DIR** . '/settings.local.php';
   }

Answer (score 1):

Good day!
Try to add in you yml file:

```
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: @NicholasByDesign Seems I have the same settings for development for my projects. And I didn't have any issues with it.. I will check setting.local.php and services.yml. Maybe I will find something..

Comment: @NicholasByDesign I noticed only one difference in the configurations of my old project
`
parameters: 
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
`

Comment: I have that as well by default :/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module to disable caches without editing settings*.php and *services.yml files. Just go to /admin/config/mix page and use the "Enable development mode" checkbox to switch between Dev/Prod modes. Here is [a screenshot about Dev mode vs. Prod mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0RuH.png)